# Parent/Child process print

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork

I'm writing a C program that creates a child process. After creating the child process, the parent process should ouput two messages: "I am the parent" then it should print "The parent is done". Same for child process "I am child" and "The child is done". However I want to make sure, the second message of the child is always done before the second message of the parent. How can I achieve to print "The child is done" and "The parent is done" rather than printing their pid?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int pid, stat_loc;


  printf("\nmy pid = %d\n", getpid());
  pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1)
    perror("error in fork");

  else if (pid ==0 )
    { 
       printf("\nI am the child process, my pid = %d\n\n", getpid());


    } 
  else  
    {
      printf("\nI am the parent process, my pid = %d\n\n", getpid());       
      sleep(2);
    }  
  printf("\nThe %d is done\n\n", getpid());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a flag variable, that is set in the parent, but then the child clears it. Then simply check for that for the last output.

Something like

```
int is_parent = 1;  // Important to create and initialize before the fork

pid = fork();

if (pid == -1) { ... }

if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("\nI am the child process, my pid = %d\n\n", getpid());
    in_parent = 0;  // We're not in the parent anymore
}
else { ... }

printf("\nThe %s is done\n\n", is_parent ? "parent" : child");
```

Comment: It works as I wanted. Thank you very much for the clear explanation of flag variable.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) in the parent process for the child to complete.

```
  else
    {
      wait(0);
      printf("\nI am the parent process, my pid = %d\n\n", getpid());
    }
```

You should check if `wait()` succeeds and `main()`'s return type should be `int`.

Comment: `wait` takes a pointer. For a _null pointer constant_ you should use the macro `NULL`, not the interger literal `0` (although technically correct). Also, what do you mean with `wait(2)`? That is definitively wrong.

Comment: @Olaf There's absolutely nothing with using `0`. See C11, 6.3.2.3. `wait(2)` refers to the fact that wait() is a Unix system call.

Comment: I'm very confident my comment clearly stated it is technically correct; just bad style. About the call: So it is `wait`, not `wait(2). If you refer to the man-page, that would be `3` for POSIX; 2 is for th Linux-manpage. OP does not specify he uses Linux, so it would be better to refer to the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Saying that's bad style is *your opinion* that I don't share. Unix existed long before POSIX came into existence and `wait()` has always been a system call. It has always been `2` for system calls.

Comment: @Olaf: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶3 "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
`void *`, is called a _null pointer constant_."  When there's a prototype in effect for `wait()`, there is no risk of confusion; `0` is a perfectly valid null pointer constant.  (There is a footnote that references NULL and `<stddef.h>` that I've not shown.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I repeat from my first comment: "you **should** ... although **technically correct**". As I learned it, "should" is a recommendation, not an imperative.

Comment: @l3x: Unix is not a standard and OP does not state he uses Unix either. there are more POSIX implementations than Unix/Linux.